# If/Else statement only runs if code even if else condition is satisfied

Tags: javascript, if-statement, switch-statement, prompt

I'm trying to make a program that talks about you favorite subjects and if you are right or left brained.

```js
function questionGame() {
var user = prompt("Are you RIGHT brained, LEFT brained, a bit of BOTH, or NEITHER?").toUpperCase();

switch (user){
 case 'RIGHT':
    var user1 = prompt("You like Art?").toUpperCase();
    if (user1 = 'YES' || 'YEAH') {
        alert("Sweet. You should check out LadyBeeSweets, she is the next michelangelo.");
    } else if (user1 = 'NO') {
        alert("Alright, ok, um, then do you like anything?");   
    } else {
        alert("I'm sorry, I don't understand " + user1 + ", please respond YES or NO next time, thank you!");
    };
     break;
 case 'LEFT':
     var user2 = prompt("Oh nice! Me too, I love my tech! Do you have a Linux-Based Operating System?").toUpperCase();
     if (user2 = 'YES') {
        alert("Sweet, me too!");   
     } else if (user2 = 'NO') {
        alert("Oh, you should definitely give one a try!")   
     } else {
       alert("I'm sorry, I don't understand " + user2 +", next time please respond with YES or NO.");  
     };
     break;
 case 'BOTH':
     var user3 = prompt("Interesting, so do you like Whales?").toUpperCase();
     if (user3 = 'YES' || 'YEAH') {
        alert("Cool."); 
     } else if (user3 = 'NO' || 'NOPE') {
        alert("You, MONSTER!"); 
     } else {
        alert("Hmm, whats that? I don't know if you like whales or not. Please reply YES or NO next time!"); 
     };
     break;
 case 'NEITHER':
     var user4 = prompt("Hmm, ok. I'm a left brainer! Do you care that I'm a Left Brainer? YES or NO?").toUpperCase();
     if (user4 = 'YES' || 'YEAH') {
        alert("Thanks for caring!");  
     } else if (user4 = 'NO' || 'NOPE') {
       alert("Wow, thanks a lot, bro.");   
     } else {
         alert("I couldn't understand " + user4 + ", please reply YES or NO next time, thank you");
     };
     break;
 default:
     alert("I'm sorry, I don't understand " + user + ", try again and chose either 'RIGHT', 'LEFT', 'BOTH', or 'NEITHER'.");
     questionGame();
     
    };
};
```

But when you enter in 'Left' in the first prompt and it asks you if you use a linux based operating system, even if you type 'no' or something random like 'guhgriubcrhmiecrc', it still runs the first if statement's code block. 
I appreciate all answers. By the Way, this is JavaScript.

Comment: `user1 = 'YES'` is not a comparison operation it is an assignment, one that evaluates to true

Comment: As @PatrickEvans says, should use something like if (user1 === 'YES' || user1 === 'YEAH') {

Comment: It worked! Thank you guys, I should've known it had to do with the = signs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the assignment operator `=` instead of the comparison operators `==` or `===` in statements like `if (user2 = 'YES')`

Answer (score 0):

As Jorg mentioned, you are assigning a variable, not comparing it. Now that you have identified this as something you do, avoid doing so in the future by putting your literals on the left of your comparisons.

```
if ('YES' === user2) {
        alert("Sweet, me too!");   
}
// If you forget to use multiple equals again, this code will throw an error and the problem will be more obvious
if ('YES' = user2) {
        alert("Oops!");   
}
```